# How can i change my xml layout into a pdf

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, textview

I tried many tutorials but I am unsatisfied. I want it to take a screenshot and then save that screenshot to a pdf file, that is conversion of the XML layout file to a pdf

Here is what I tried to do.

```
 private void createPdf() {
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this.bitmap, this.bitmap.getWidth(), this.bitmap.getHeight(), true);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    document.finishPage(page);
    File file = new File(path);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String targetPdf = path+"test-2.pdf";
    File filePath = new File(targetPdf);
    try {
        document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("main", "error "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  
    // document.close();

    document.close();
}

private void openPdf(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open FIle");
    try{
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Apps to read PDF FIle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by `I am unsatisfied?` and what exactly you need to be improved?. Also please post a [minmal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The Codes that i found on internet didnt worked they showed an exception.